# How is the datetime checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I press the button with 'gnd' id I want to give the alert if the datetime is not selected. but somehow I did not get the datetime value. How do I solve?

**datetime**

```
div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Date to redial", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="date" name="callDate2" id="callDate2" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
```

**Button;**

```
$("#gnd").click(function () {
            var valueDate = document.getElementById("#callDate2").value;
            if (!valueDate)
            {
                alert("please select date!");
            }
        });
```

Comment: document.getElementById should contain only id.pls remove "#"

var valueDate = document.getElementById("callDate2").value;

Comment: but this time it gives an alert and is still updating :/

Comment: Should I add this? "return false"

Comment: check the value of "valueDate" in console.log(valueDate).based on that try if loop

Comment: its work. thx 4 comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove # from id

```
var valueDate = document.getElementById("callDate2").value;
```

Comment: thanks for comment worked

Comment: it's my pleasure